# Change TextBox Value and Update On Ajax Call

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working on an ecommerce site where I am stuck on the cart management. Basically before login, products are kept in a session and I am trying to update the product quantity stored in the session using Ajax. I mean whenever I write in the '**Quantity To Change**', the changed value should be reflected in the '**Quantity**' column.

**Note:** I've shortened the post and figured out why it wasn't firing while debugging. Actually I was unable to get the id of the associated product. Now it passes the id. That's it. Now I've another issue - The TextBox are being created dynamically with a for loop. I used developer tools to figure out how the TextBoxes are generated dynamically and it is something like this:

```
For Product 1: cartDetails_0__Quantity
For Product 2: cartDetails_1__Quantity
```

I am wondering how to grab the quantity or values from the dynamically generated TextBoxes. If I put the generated id from HTML directly to Ajax, then it updates the quantity. Otherwise it doesn't. I've tried to use a loop in Ajax but I think, I am getting it wrong. Please see the **View**.

The view:

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Name</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Price</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity To Change</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (ViewBag.CartDetails != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cartDetails.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; display:none;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].ProductId)</td>
                    <td id="ID" style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].ProductName)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].Price)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].Quantity, new { @class = "quantityUpdate" })</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => cartDetails[i].Quantity, new { @class = "quantity", data_id = cartDetails[i].ProductId } )</td>
            </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCart")';
$(".quantityUpdate").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    var i = 0;
    $('.quantityUpdate').each(function (i, item) {
        $.post(url, { id: id, Quantity: $("#cartDetails_"+i+"__Quantity").val() }, function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $("#TotalPrice").load(window.location + " #TotalPrice");
            }
        });
    })

    alert(id);
    alert($("#cartDetails_"+i+"__Quantity").val());
});
```

Here is an image sample that I am trying:

[image: Update On Quantity Change]

Comment: You are debugging in the browser right? It will never hit the debugger in visual studio as its client side (not server side) code. Is the code being reached when the page loads to register the event? Also your post method on the server should accept an object and not 2 parameters unless you want to change your ajax to send it by url instead.

Comment: Actually I tried to debug in the controller. There is a method in Ajax and if it hits atleast in it, then I could understand. Right now, trying to solve it.

Comment: I was not very clear, sorry. I assumed the code was not reaching your ajax call in the javascript and that is where you were putting your breakpoint. That is step 1, see if your ajax call is even firing. You need to do that from the browser. You can debug it with a breakpoint or see what (if any) the network activity is from the browser. Once you get that to fire then figure out if (or why not) its hitting the controller.

Comment: I've put the breakpoint in the controller to see if it passes the associated id and quantity for a specific product. But it doesn't fire up.

Comment: You need to see if it is not being hit because you are 1) calling it wrong or 2) not calling it at all.  You do this from the browser. You can debug your javascript in the browser using the debug tools provided in the browser.

Comment: I've figured out why it wasn't firing. Now it works perfect. But I've another issue. Please see the post and it's updated regarding dynamically generated id for TextBoxes. I am wondering how to pass the id in Ajax.

Comment: I was able to solve it. Just kept the quantity in a variable like this: var quantity = $(this).val(); Now this takes the quantity from the associated TextBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to call ajax when you change the value in .quality textbox then this is how you should do:

```
$('.quantity').change(function(){
   //your ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('.quantity').change(function(){
       $('.quantityUpdate').val($('.quantity').val());
    // put code here
  });
```

Instant Change

```
   $('.quantity').keyup(function(){
      $('.quantityUpdate').val($('.quantity').val());
      // put code here
  });
```