# Get Dynamically Created TextBox ID From Razor To jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get the dynamically created TextBox ID into jQuery from Razor view. The IDs are created in HTML as follows:

```
Product - 1: cartDetails_0__Quantity
Product - 2: cartDetails_1__Quantity
```

Right now, when I give the above inputs directly to Ajax call, it updates the corresponding rows. As an example:

```
 @if (ViewBag.Cart != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cartDetails.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => cartDetails[i].Id)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].IP)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].ProductName)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.DisplayFor(model => cartDetails[i].Price)</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center;">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => cartDetails[i].Quantity, new { @class = "quantityUpdate", data_id = cartDetails[i].Id })</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

var url = '@Url.Action("UpdateCart2")';
$(".quantityUpdate").change(function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $('.quantityUpdate').each(function (i, item) {
        $.post(url, { id: id, quantity: $('#cartDetails_' + 0 + '__Quantity').val() }, function (response) { //cartDetails_0__Quantity - The first TextBox ID
            if (response) {
                $("#TotalPrice").load(window.location + " #TotalPrice");
            }
        });
    })
    alert($('#cartDetails_' + 0 + '__Quantity').val());
});
```

Is there any way to loop through jQuery to get the dynamically generated TextBox ID in Razor? I've tried the following but doesn't get the value:

```
 $('.quantityUpdate').each(function (i, item) {
        $.post(url, { id: id, quantity: $('#cartDetails_' + i + '__Quantity').val() }, function (response) { //cartDetails_0__Quantity - The first TextBox ID
            if (response) {
                $("#TotalPrice").load(window.location + " #TotalPrice");
            }
        });
    })
```

Even tried this one but it gets the value of first TextBox only:

```
     $('.quantityUpdate').each(function (i, item) {
        $.post(url, { id: id, quantity: $(this).val() }, function (response) { //cartDetails_0__Quantity - The first TextBox ID
            if (response) {
                $("#TotalPrice").load(window.location + " #TotalPrice");
            }
        });
    })
```

**Note**: I am trying to update rows giving input to the TextBoxes with Ajax call. The TextBoxes are in a loop in the view. In this regards, I've to get the IDs of the dynamically generated HTML IDs.

Comment: Any error in the browser console ?

Comment: No error at all. Just unable to get the corresponding TextBox ID.

Comment: I did a little example here : https://jsfiddle.net/8gh8ugke/ it seems working with ids like yours

Comment: I've seen your example and it works. But in my case, I am not sure, why it does get the required value I mean not getting the associated TextBox value. It isn't updating the recently given value to the TextBox I mean the quantity. Here is an image that I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39142704

Comment: I was able to solve it. Just kept the quantity in a variable like this: var quantity = $(this).val(); Now this takes the quantity from the associated TextBoxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create event of dynamically created elements in order to get their Ids. 
But bear in mind to use this you need to use On(). See   http://api.jquery.com/on/

See also:
[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)
[In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

PS. If there is a cleaner way to get dynamically created elements I would also be glad to get it :)

**Edit.** Maybe I was not clear enough . There is no exactly "create" event. You just can hook any actions you need to On()

See also [jQuery "on create" event for dynamically-created elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268661/jquery-on-create-event-for-dynamically-created-elements)